# Validating regex number MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have this table:

```
client(client_id, name, surname, number, snils)
```

I created a trigger to validate phone number, regex is correct, but trigger doesn't pass my insert. But it should pass. I can't figure out the issue.

Trigger:

```
delimiter |
create trigger validate_number before insert on client for each row
begin
if new.number not rlike '^7\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|^7[0-9]{10}'
then
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'bad number';
end if;
end|
```

Output:

```
mysql> insert into client(client_id, name, surname, number, snils) values
-> (11, 'Sergey','Makareivch','74958477301', "11111111111");
ERROR 1644 (45000): Invalid phone number format
```

Comment: Note that you use `BEFORE INSERT ON employee` while you reference the "*client*" table. If these two are really the same table, then your error [is not reproducible](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bRN5GMUj7Hw1XE6FCJcqKC/0).

Comment: @lemon yeah sorry, I took the friend's trigger, it uses employee table, but I use client table. So nothing except the name doesn't change

Comment: Try running your code in the fiddle link I've provided in my previous comment.

Comment: Lol... Idk, it doesn't work for me in workbench and command line mysql client...

Comment: Check the declaration of the tables and field types.